# Notepad++ find and replace a constant string

Tags: notepad++, regex

Using notepad++ I have the following text.

```
This little piggy went to market, \cite{smith1774}
This little \cite{ben1864} piggy stayed \cite{mueller2867} home,
This little piggy had roast beef
```

I want to find and remove all the `\cite{..}` so i am only left with the nursery rhyme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search Menu, Replace

Search Mode: Regular Expression

Find:     `\\cite\{[^{]*\}`
Replace:   (nothing)

Match:

```
\\    - literal backslash
cite  - the word cite
\{    - literal {
[^{]* - any number of any character other than {
\}    - literal }
```

Comment: great, thanks for the explanation. Can you recommend any tutorials which outlines these search commands

Comment: The documentation: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions

Comment: [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)